# Cast String into Date in BIGQUERY When Date is in the following format: M/D/YYYY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a string that is a date and it is in M/D/YYYY  ie:

```
1/1/2018
12/31/2018
```

I get an invalid date error ( it shows: '2/18/2018' as the invalid date)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below is example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '1/1/2018' date_as_string UNION ALL
  SELECT '12/31/2018'
)
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', date_as_string) date_as_date
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with output:

```sql
Row date_as_date     
1   2018-01-01   
2   2018-12-31
```