# How do I insert a row in bigquery with a column of type DATE

Tags: python, sql, json, database, google-bigquery

Just started BigQuery and SQL yesterday so I am rather new at it, and I can't figure out how to do this properly.

I get the following error:

> Could not cast literal '"2020-12-27"' to type DATE

This is my code:

```
dateNow = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# connect to bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
table_id = "xxxxx"
table = client.get_table(table_id)

# write to loans
query = "INSERT INTO `xxxxx` (username,id,date) VALUES ('\"{}\"','\"{}\"','\"{}\"')".format(username, id, dateNow)
query_job = client.query(query)
results = query_job.result()
```

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074680/cast-string-into-date-in-bigquery-when-date-is-in-the-following-format-m-d-yyyy) answer could help you

Answer (score 0):

After messing around for a while got this to work:

query = "INSERT INTO xxx (username,id,date) VALUES ('"{}"','"{}"',CURRENT_DATE())".format(username, id)

Answer (score 0):

The error you were getting means that you were trying to insert string literal, which could not be cast to the DATE-type expression. The reason is having additional two double quotes inside single quotes.

The rules for implicit coercion of string to date are described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#date_literals) as following:

> String literals in canonical date format also implicitly coerce to DATE type when used where a DATE-type expression is expected.

I would fix your code by **removing double quotes** around date literal. Note the third curly brackets in the INSERT statement string without double quotes.

```
dateNow = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# connect to bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
table_id = "xxxxx"
table = client.get_table(table_id)

# write to loans
query = "INSERT INTO `xxxxx` (username,id,date) VALUES ('\"{}\"','\"{}\"','{}')".format(username, id, dateNow)
query_job = client.query(query)
results = query_job.result()
```

Or you can always use the function [PARSE_DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date), which can help you to parse string literal to date in the format you specify. But I believe this is not your case, because you already have the date in the correct format.